# Select&Distinct into new object with DLinq

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose that I have list of following objects

```
public class OrderInfo
{
    public string OrderNo {get; set;}
    public DateTime OrderDate {get; set;}
    public decimal OrderAmount {get; set;}
    public decimal OrderPrice {get; set;}
}
```

as

```
List<OrderInfo> data = new List<OrderInfo>();
```

and this list has necessary number of items in it.

I need to select distinct OrderNo, OrderDate pairs from this List. In Linq I can write a query as:

```
var q = (from x in data
         group x by new { x.OrderNo, x.OrderDate }
         into grp
         select new
         {
             grp.Key.OrderNo,
             grp.Key.OrderDate
         }).Distinct();
```

The thing is that I am writing a generic method so the object type and properties are unknown. So I have to write this with DLinq.

If I have a list of `List<T>` and a `string[] { "OrderNo", "OrderDate" }` how can I apply this example with DLinq at the run-time?

Comment: Let that object inherit from interface, and then set the type constraint that the type <T> must inherhit from the interface

Comment: That would not help much, because this is a generalized method which should run with any type. And those types do not necesarily mean to have anything in common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my fault. I was Googling for "*DLinq*" but not "*Dynamic LinQ*". Actually the answer was quite simple :

```
var q = data.Select("new (OrderNo, OrderDate)").Distinct();
```